# Cordova 2.2 iOS ChildBrowser Plugin Will Not Work

Tags: cordova-2.0.0

I am having trouble getting the iOS version of the ChildBrowser plugin working with Cordova 2.2.0. I updated to the latest version as of 2012/11/26, of the ChildBrowser plugin and it now builds, but child windows do not open.

I had an earlier version of this plugin working with Cordova 2.0.0 building on Snow Leopard with xcode 4.2, but of course I need to upgrade to Cordova 2.2 to build for iOS 6. I'm using a completely new Cordova 2.2 project, into which I copied the www folder and modified appropriately.

I'm using the latest childbrowser.js file, and Cordova.plist has the appropriate lines.

I tried updating the old xcode 4.2 project with the latest version of the plugin, and it no longer builds, giving an undeclared identifier error for "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait" in ChildBrowserViewController.m, the same error I was getting when I was trying to build the Cordova 2.2 project with an earlier version of the plugin.

Comment: I'm hitting the same error.  You can actually comment out that line of code just to muddle through, but I'm eagerly awaiting what reply you get.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to add also ChildBrowserViewController.xib besides the .h and .m files to Plugins folder by dragging the file from the Finder into XCode.